# How to re.search module on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

In a part of my program, I have to check an email entered and I want to make it so any domain name can work for the checker, current code as below;

```
import re #needed to check email
emailFormat = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w+$' #general form of email

def check(email):  #Validation for email
    if(re.search(emailFormat,email)): #pass expression and string in  search() 
        return "Valid Email"
    else:  
        return "Invalid Email"

enterEmail=str(input('enter email'))

print(check(enterEmail))
```

Currently, this will work for any email in for example@email.com but as some emails are in the form example@email.co.uk  so how can I can make 'emailFormat' valid for any domain form. Also, the check will work for company/school emails, for example, example@school.com or example@email.school just anything which doesn't contain a 'two-part' domain name like 'co.uk' so will I need another variable to check for that or is it possible to do in one command.

Thanks in advance for anything useful.

Comment: [how to use regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

Comment: [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) fits a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on the two letters domains as well, and on email.school as well.

```
import re #needed to check email
emailFormat = r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)"

def check(email):  #Validation for email
    if(re.search(emailFormat,email)): #pass expression and string in  search()
        return "Valid Email"
    else:
        return "Invalid Email"

enterEmail=str(input('enter email'))

print(check(enterEmail))
```

Further reading on the above :- https://emailregex.com/

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code and choose the maximum subdomain count. according to [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/841281/amount-of-allowed-subdomains-in-domain-and-email), the email limitation is 255 bytes therefore it is not possible for having more than about 120 subdomains!
try 30 subdomains, I think it's more than enough.

```
import re  # needed to check email

def CheckEmail(email):  # Validation for email
    '''
    Validation for Email

    input:
    email as "String"

    output: ( validation, Email Parts ) as tuple
    Validation as "String"
    Email Parts as if Valid as List, otherwise None
    '''

    # Can be decreased. The maximum is 125. according to the link below, the email limmitation is 255 bytes.
    subDomainCount = 30

    # This is a subdomain pattern
    subDomainPattern = r"\.?([\w-]+)?"

    # General form of email with maximum subDomainCount parameter
    pattern = r"([\w\.-]+)@" + r"([\w-]+)" + (subDomainPattern * subDomainCount) + r"\.([\w-]+)"

    # Validation: True, False
    emailIsValid = re.search(pattern, email)

    # Conditional Statement
    if emailIsValid:

        # Condition multiple dots with no letters between them
        dotpattern = r"[\.]{2}"
        if re.search(dotpattern,email):
            return "Invalid Email", None

        # Finding Email Parts (user + domains)
        emailParts = emailIsValid.groups()
        
        # removing empty subdomains
        emailParts = [x for x in emailParts if x is not None]
        
        return "Valid Email", emailParts
    else:
        return "Invalid Email", None



enteredEmail = input("Enter Email: ")
(validation, emailParts) = CheckEmail(enteredEmail)
print(validation)
print("Email Parts:",emailParts)
```

The Terminal:

```
Enter Email: test3475@website.acro.us
Valid Email
Email Parts: ['test3475', 'website', 'acro', 'us']
```

```
Enter Email: test_third@mail.rop.qot.wkfc.org
Valid Email
Email Parts: ['test_third', 'mail', 'rop', 'qot', 'wkfc', 'org']
```

```
Enter Email: testmega@mail..com
Invalid Email
Email Parts: None
```

```
Enter Email: testbored@mail
Invalid Email
Email Parts: None
```

You can make subDomainCount parameter be varied by considering the length of the inputted email from the user but I think it's not necessary.
if you want to learn more about the re module, I myself learned it from [SoloLearn](https://www.sololearn.com/). (inside the Python3 course you can find Module 9: Regular Expressions.

Comment: Probably a little excessive for what I need to achieve but still greatly appreciated, especially if I ever go back and refine the program.